# JavaFX: why dragged image size is lower than original?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag&drop for ListView each cell of which is a GridPane. So, I'm just making snapshot of a corresponding GridPane and set is drag view.

```java
WritableImage im = rootPane.snapshot(null, null);
dragboard.setDragView(im);
```

The problem is that size of drag view image is somehow scaled down and I have no idea why is that.

[image]

I've tried to scale snapshot image but has no luck.

```java
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)(5 * getWidth()), (int)(5 * getHeight()));
SnapshotParameters sp =  new SnapshotParameters();
sp.setTransform(Transform.scale(5, 5));
WritableImage im = rootPane.snapshot(sp, writableImage);
```

Could someone please explain how to show real image size when dragging.

**EDIT:**

Minimal reproducible example. Also I've noticed that the size of the drag view depends on... scene size. The larger scene size the lower drag view will be

```java
public class Launcher extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        ListView<Foo> fooList = new ListView<>();
        pane.setCenter(fooList);
        fooList.setCellFactory(list -> new FooCell());
        fooList.getItems().setAll(List.of(new Foo("1"), new Foo("2"), new Foo("3"), new Foo("4")));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1400, 900);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> Platform.exit());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static class Foo {

        public String a;

        public Foo(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Foo foo = (Foo) o;

            return a.equals(foo.a);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return a.hashCode();
        }
    }

    static class FooCell extends ListCell<Foo> {

        private AnchorPane rootPane;
        private GridPane gridPane;
        private Region dragHandle;
        private TextField textField;
        private HBox hbox;

        public FooCell() {
            ListCell<Foo> thisCell = this;

            rootPane = new AnchorPane();

            gridPane = new GridPane();
            gridPane.setPrefHeight(40);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(gridPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(gridPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(gridPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(gridPane, 0d);
            rootPane.getChildren().setAll(gridPane);

            dragHandle = new Region();
            dragHandle.setMinWidth(30);

            setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) return;

                ObservableList<Foo> items = getListView().getItems();
                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(getItem().a);
                dragboard.setDragView(gridPane.snapshot(null, null));
                dragboard.setContent(content);
                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }
                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(0.3);
                }
            });

            setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(1);
                }
            });

            setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) return;


                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;

                if (db.hasString()) {
                    ObservableList<Foo> items = getListView().getItems();
                    int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(new Foo(db.getString()));
                    int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                    items.set(draggedIdx, getItem());
                    items.set(thisIdx, new Foo(db.getString()));

                    List<Foo> itemscopy = new ArrayList<>(getListView().getItems());
                    getListView().getItems().setAll(itemscopy);
                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);

            textField = new TextField();
            hbox = new HBox();

            ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col0.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
            gridPane.add(dragHandle, 0, 0, 1, 10);

            ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
            col1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            gridPane.add(textField, 1, 0, 1, 1);
            gridPane.add(hbox, 1, 1, 10, 1);

            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col0, col1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Foo item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }

            textField.setText(item.a);
            setGraphic(rootPane);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2 (problem identified):**

It's OS (or display manager to be more precise) who's scaling dragged image down. Seems like GTK backend that JavaFX uses implements kind of limitation for dragged images. If image width is greater than 300-350px it will be scaled down. I've found out this simply trying to drag various pics in my email client. Small or medium images doesn't change, but larger ones being scaled. What I've said about it depends on scene size was right, but there's no magic here. When you change scene size, you change target node size as well. When its width become close to 300px.. yeah, it was obvious, but I paid no attention.

Generally my problem is that I want to drag images that have large width, but low height. That's why scaling looks so ugly/ It makes text unreadable due to extra low font size. Funny that Electron doesn't have such problem. Either Chromium doesn't use GTK API for dragging or DOM doesn't have such issues by definition.

Comment: Have you tried calling shapshot on the object you are dragging instead of the root pane?

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 Yes, i've tried to make snapshot of text field, same issue. Though it makes no sense. I need a whole list cell image, because this is what unique represent an object, not just a part of it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of with what I have to work with is use the component layout bounds for dimensions. I think I recall that using getWidth() and getHeight() on JavaFX nodes was unreliable.  I'll try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 Tnx, I've added minimal reproducible example. I still don't understand how it supposed to work but the key is scene size. E.g when size is 400x400 drag view is almost 1:1 to original pane, but when scene size is 1400x900 it scaled down dramatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the OS scaling the image to avoid covering too much of the screen?

Comment: @Slaw This is definitely not a snapshot problem, because if I save it to file it has normal size. So, yeah, something is scaling image when it's being dragged. But OS (Fedora + Gnome3)? Why should it? Image size 525x40, scene size 1400x900, screen size 1920x1080. As I've discovered dragging image is scaled down depending on scene size. So I suppose it's JavaFX issue.

Comment: You may need to set your viewport manually in SnapshotParameters with setViewport()

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 Nope, I've tried this before. Anyway, it doesn't matter anymore, because Slaw was absolutely correct. I've updated my question. Tnx for the help though!

Comment: @Slaw if you will post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Eh, I don't feel confident enough to post an answer. It was just a guess. And while you seem to have confirmed it, that doesn't mean JavaFX isn't also doing something or that there's no workaround. I also don't have any official sources supporting my guess.

Comment: @Slaw It was a good guess, tnx. I've checked JavaFX [sources](https://github.com/jgneff/javafx-graphics/blob/master/src/javafx.graphics/classes/com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumClipboard.java). JavaFX doesn't resize drag image, so it's a native thing. I've also found confimation for [web browsers](https://transitory.technology/set-drag-image/), but I'm to lazy to dig up Gnome sources.